Combining model ARIMA and GARCH models
prices = Import["your_file_path_here", "Data"][[;; 100]]
arimaModel = TimeSeriesModelFit[prices, "ARIMA"]
residuals = TimeSeriesForecast[arimaModel, 1]
garchModel = EstimatedProcess[residuals, GARCHProcess[1, 1]]

arimaForecast = TimeSeriesForecast[arimaModel, {100}]

garchVolatility = 
  TimeSeriesForecast[garchModel["ConditionalVariance"], {100}]

combinedForecast = 
 TimeSeriesThread[Plus, {arimaForecast, garchVolatility}]

combinedForecast


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i want to predict the next 100 days price using combination of ARIMA and GARCH model i using the last 100 days price as dataset using to predict the coming 100 days Mr.Domen yestarday help by editing the code and using that code i get the result but it is same as the dataset i already given i hope it is correct

no the result is wrong
